# Advantages of Enabling Firmware Password Protection

Tags: mac, security, disk-encryption, firmware, filevault

What security advantages, if any, would be gained by enabling Firmware Password Protection on a mac that already has filevault encryption for the disk?

Answer (score 0):

It's the equivalent of a door requiring a separate key for the deadbolt.

You now need both keys to get in.

Also, the Firmware Password Protection prevents the user from being able to choose the boot device.